# MacOS LLDB | Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1 & 2, address=0x123456789)

Tags: c++, macos, assembly, x86-64

So to start, I am not too knowledageble in C++, I know very little from a class I took a while back. Almost everything I have so far is from this very generous and knowledgable community.

I have to use a wack piece of custom software for work on MacOS and it doesn't have any form autosave and it occasionally likes to crash. Though I regularly save, its annoying loosing any amount of work because it crashes.

What I am trying to do is use the save function address to save and repeat every 5 or so minutes. So far I have the process id, the runtime base memory address for the process, the offset of the save function address(I have subtracted the disassembler base address from the address I found with debugging and disassembling), and the arguments it requires. When I try to run the save function I get the lldb error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10a106ecf) and sometimes it changes to Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x10a106ecf). I have found other questions about this error on this website, but it either doesn't apply to my situation, or due to my limited knowledge I just don't understand how to solve it for my case. If anyone could explain in detail what I am doing wrong in detail along with a solution, it would be much appreciated because I would like to get an understanding and learn.

The project is a Command Line Utility in Xcode. I'm not sure if it would need to be a .dylib and added into the process, but if it could be an external command line utility, that would be more optimal for me.

Here is the problem code:

```cpp
mach_vm_address_t runtimeBase = 0; // Base process memory address. Set in the getProc() function
mach_vm_address_t funcBase = 0x973ECF; // Function Address from disassembling. (0x100973ECF - 0x100000000 = 0x973ECF)

int main()
{
    if (!getProc()) throw std::logic_error("Failed to get Process.");
    
    typedef mach_vm_address_t(__cdecl* autoSave)(int saveType, const char* saveMessage);
    autoSave save = (autoSave)(runtimeBase + funcBase);
    for(;;)
    {
        save(0, "AutoSave");//    <-- Error Here: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1/2, address=0x10a106ecf)
        //sleep(5); //add sleep after I get save to work.
    }
}

/*
 saveType:
    0 = Save local.
    1 = Save server.
 
 saveMessage: Message for history/save log.
 */
```

More detail I get from code=1 error is:

```cpp
error: memory read failed for 0x10a106e00  <-- Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10a106ecf)
```

And for code=2 is:

```cpp
0x10a106ecf: addb   %al, (%rax)            <-- Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x10a106ecf)
0x10a106ed1: addb   %al, (%rax)
0x10a106ed3: addb   %al, (%rax)
0x10a106ed5: addb   %al, (%rax)
0x10a106ed7: addb   %al, (%rax)
0x10a106ed9: addb   %al, (%rax)
0x10a106edb: addb   %al, (%rax)
0x10a106edd: addb   %al, (%rax)
0x10a106edf: addb   %al, (%rax)
0x10a106ee1: addb   %al, (%rax)
0x10a106ee3: addb   %al, (%rax)
0x10a106ee5: addb   %al, (%rax)
0x10a106ee7: addb   %al, (%rax)
0x10a106ee9: addb   %al, (%rax)
0x10a106eeb: addb   %al, (%rax)
0x10a106eed: addb   %al, (%rax)
```

Comment: `addb   %al, (%rax)` is how `00 00` decodes.   Crashing there indicates that execution jumped to some memory that's all zeros, perhaps due to overwriting a return address or function pointer.  Or if you have any hand-written asm, due to getting something wrong with the stack.

Comment: @PeterCordes No hand written assembly in the program, and when I print the runtime address of the function from adding the runtime base and view the assembly instruction in runtime, everything matches up with what I see in IDA. I'm thinking code=2 is directly related to code=1 (memory read failed)which I would assume would just get all 0's. I just dont know what the addresses are, the address after code=1/2 match up with the correct address of the runtime function. Would the other addresses be the address of where the error is in my program? Also, thanks for your comment!

Comment: The `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x10a106ecf)` is from trying to deref whatever garbage is in RAX, for read+write.  The `00 00` garbage machine code decodes as instructions that try to access that "bad pointer".   I haven't used LLDB much, or MacOS for development at all, but I'm guessing code=1 vs 2 might be read vs. write. (And I haven't really looked at the details of your question, just wanted to help out by explaining that seeing execution in a whole block of `addb   %al, (%rax)` instructions means you jumped to a region full of zeros; any mem access it attempts is already bogus.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Any information helps. Like I said in the post, I know little c++ and even less about assembly, but I have generally understood your explanations. Thanks for helping out and taking time to comment and explain, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @PeterCordes I solved my problem and updated the post with an (hopefully correct)explanation. I just wanted to let you know so you can understand the reasoning behind why it happened more incase you come across someone who is having a similar issue using MacOS and LLDB. Again, thank you for your explanations, they were very helpful in resolving my problem.
(Note: I dont know if Stack Exchange notifies when a post is modified that you commented on so if that's true then sorry for the double notifications. )

Comment: You're fine on notifications, SO only pings people on change if they manually "follow" a question.  Otherwise they might happen to see it bumped up in the "active" question list, but that's separate.  Anyway, please don't edit an answer into the question.  You can and should post your answer as a proper answer, with the "answer my own question" button.  So do that, and roll back your question.  (Definitely don't put [solved] into the title; clicking the checkmark under the vote arrows on your answer will mark the question as having an accepted answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With assembly explanations from [@Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) I managed to solve my issue.

> [@Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes): `addb   %al, (%rax)` is how `00 00` decodes. Crashing there indicates that execution jumped to some memory that's all zeros, perhaps due to overwriting a return address or function pointer. Or if you have any hand-written asm, due to getting something wrong with the stack.

> [@Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes): The `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x10a106ecf)` is from trying to deref whatever garbage is in RAX, for read+write. The `00 00` garbage machine code decodes as instructions that try to access that "bad pointer". I haven't used LLDB much, or MacOS for development at all, but I'm guessing code=1 vs 2 might be read vs. write. (And I haven't really looked at the details of your question, just wanted to help out by explaining that seeing execution in a whole block of `addb   %al, (%rax)` instructions means you jumped to a region full of zeros; any mem access it attempts is already bogus.)

---

So, as [@Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) said  `addb   %al, (%rax)` is how `00 00` decodes. Crashing there indicates that execution jumped to some memory that's all zeros.

From this we can infer that when `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x10a106ecf)` happens it is because we jumped to a place in memory that is all zeros. But why are we jumping to a place in memory with all zeros? I am thinking it's because of how MacOS handles memory. Each process has its own memory space, and I was trying to jump to the address `0x10a106e00` in MY OWN process' memory, which does not exist. There are a multitude of resources explain how process memory works on modern OS's, just do a quick google search if you want to learn more.

So what we know now is:

- `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10a106ecf)` happens because my program fails to read the memory for the specified address.
- `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x10a106ecf)` happens because we are jumping an invalid place in memory, and for the wrong process.

There was also some issues with the code, I was using code better suited for Windows, To create a function based on the memory address I did,

```cpp
typedef mach_vm_address_t(__cdecl* autoSave)(int saveType, const char* saveMessage);
    autoSave save = (autoSave)(runtimeBase + funcBase);
```

And this is what I'm thinking a better/correct way of creating a function based on the memory address is:

```cpp
int (*autoSave)(int saveType, const char* saveMessage) = (int (*)(int , const char *))(runtimeBase + funcBase);
```

The last thing I did was create a Dylib instead of a Command Line Utility. I did this because it is MUCH easier to access the target process' memory. Though what I am trying to achieve is probably possible through a Command Line Utility(CLU) and attaching to the target process as if the CLU was a debugger or some other method, for me it was much simpler and easier to just create a dylib.

If anyone reading this has any questions about my explanation, or want more detailed explanation/example of my solution. Feel free to send me a message or comment.

I once again want to thank [@Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) for his explanations. They helped even though they said `I haven't used LLDB much, or MacOS for development at all'. The explanations were still extremely helpful and were explained in an easy to understand way.